# 2020-02-29 minus one year caused error ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query as:

```sql
select to_date('2020-02-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - interval '1' year from dual
```

I think the result should be `2019-02-28`, but oracle throws error as:

> Error report -
> ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

Comment: Funny, I think it should be `2019-03-01`.. Perhaps this is why there is an error instead

Comment: @CaiusJard: FWIW, Postgres, SQL Server, DB2, MySQL and Java do return `2019-02-28`

Comment: I've always considered that the 32nd of March is the same thing as the 1st of April; clearly the developers of those systems work to a different logic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is [the documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705); it even gives this as an example:

> When interval calculations return a datetime value, the result must be
>   an actual datetime value or the database returns an error. For
>   example, the next two statements return errors:
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_DATE('31-AUG-2004','DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('0-1')
>   FROM DUAL;
>
> SELECT TO_DATE('29-FEB-2004','DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('1-0')
>   FROM DUAL;
> ```
>
> The first fails because adding one month to a 31-day month would
>   result in September 31, which is not a valid date. The second fails
>   because adding one year to a date that exists only every four years is
>   not valid. However, the next statement succeeds, because adding four
>   years to a February 29 date is valid:
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_DATE('29-FEB-2004', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('4-0')
>   FROM DUAL;
>
> TO_DATE('
> ---------
> 29-FEB-08
> ```

The alternative is to use `add_months(..., -12)` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html)), which won't error:

```
select add_months(date '2020-02-29', -12) from dual;

ADD_MONTHS
----------
2019-02-28
```

But note how that deals with different number of days in the month; not really an issue when you're going back exactly a year, but still something to be aware of:

> If *date* is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of *date*, then the result is the last day of the resulting month.

So some of these *might* not do what you expected:

```
with rcte (dt) as (
  select last_day(date '2020-01-01')
  from dual
  union all
  select last_day(trunc(dt, 'MM') + interval '1' month)
  from rcte
  where dt < date '2020-06-01'
)
select dt,
  add_months(dt, -12) as minus12, add_months(dt, -3) as minus3, add_months(dt, -1) as minus1,
  add_months(dt, 1) as plus1, add_months(dt, 3) as plus3, add_months(dt, 12) as plus12
from rcte
order by dt;

DT         MINUS12    MINUS3     MINUS1     PLUS1      PLUS3      PLUS12    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2020-01-31 2019-01-31 2019-10-31 2019-12-31 2020-02-29 2020-04-30 2021-01-31
2020-02-29 2019-02-28 2019-11-30 2020-01-31 2020-03-31 2020-05-31 2021-02-28
2020-03-31 2019-03-31 2019-12-31 2020-02-29 2020-04-30 2020-06-30 2021-03-31
2020-04-30 2019-04-30 2020-01-31 2020-03-31 2020-05-31 2020-07-31 2021-04-30
2020-05-31 2019-05-31 2020-02-29 2020-04-30 2020-06-30 2020-08-31 2021-05-31
2020-06-30 2019-06-30 2020-03-31 2020-05-31 2020-07-31 2020-09-30 2021-06-30
```

Comment: Thanks @alex-poole.Not sure why oracle doesn't fix this interval issue.